# The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception

Tags: c#, generics

Do I need a constraint in the following code to solve the above compiler error:

```
private T GetResponse<T, TError>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
    }

    else
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            var ex = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TError>().Result;
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I'm calling the above as follows:

```
public int MyMethod(string param)
{
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, param).Result;
    return GetResponse<int, MyException>(response);
}
```

`MyException` does derive from `System.Exception`, however I get the above compiler error. Is a constraint needed?

Comment: Why not simply try it out?

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to:

```
private T GetResponse<T, TError>(HttpResponseMessage response) where TError : Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `throw` statement requires the type to derive from `Exception`. A constraint would fix this.

```
private T GetResponse<T, TError>(HttpResponseMessage response)
    where TError : Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `where TError : Exception` to the method definition.

Answer (score 0):

During **compile-time** it´s not clear that `ex` actually *is* an exception. The compiler only knows that it is of type `TError` which may or may not implement `Exception`. Although you provide the type when calling `GetResponse<int, MyException>(response)` the compiler does not have any chance that `TError`is *allways* of that given type - so *within* your generic method there is no knowledge on that type at all. What should the compiler do if you´d about to write something like `GetResponse<int, MyType>(response)` instead?

As the `throw`-statement expects an instance of `Excpetion` you´ll need a type-constraint for `TError` as you´ve already supposed.